# Compiling Mongo on Alpine

Tags: linux, mongodb, busybox, alpine-linux

I'm attempting to compile Mongo on Alpine Linux.

Anybody know how to get past this error?

```
In file included from src/mongo/util/net/socket_poll.h:20:0,
                 from src/mongo/util/net/sock.cpp:42:
/usr/include/sys/poll.h:1:2: error: #warning redirecting incorrect #include <sys/poll.h> to <poll.h> [-Werror=cpp]
 #warning redirecting incorrect #include <sys/poll.h> to <poll.h>
  ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
scons: *** [build/linux2/normal/mongo/util/net/sock.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from the build system adding a `-Werror` flag and therefore the compiler is treating warnings as errors and fails the build.

You'll probably be able to go past this step by using the *ad hoc* `--disable-warnings-as-errors` flag.

Comment: linke this? scons --disable-warnings-as-errors mongo

Comment: That worked. Now I'm getting a new error - because I don't have the glibc headers and I'm not sure how to install them on alpine/busybox - 

src/mongo/util/processinfo_linux2.cpp:23:30: fatal error: gnu/libc-version.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gnu/libc-version.h>

Comment: @DouglasFerguson not sure wether this still is current for you, but MongoDB requires glibc, whereas Alpine is compiled against microlibc, iirc.